# Subfolders in xcode. Linking

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I added a subfolder to my project(blue folder in xcode) and specify to search headers in all subfolders. Now headers are found, but after compilation project can't link. I suppose this is because my subfolder isn't compiling. But when i added subfolder in compile source in Build Phase pane nothing has changed. Strange thing that i can't add only one file from this subfolder to compile source.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is a difference between source not compiling and header not found--which is it?

Comment: Headers are found. After adding user header path. Now i can't link project. The compiler gives me a lot of linking errors.

Comment: What kind of linking errors? Symbol not found? Have you included the relevant source files in the relevant build target(s)?

Comment: Undefined symbols(Mach-O linker error). I added screenshot with what i included. But i don't sure that it's what i need to do. But if there are files in the root directory, I can add these files here. But if files in the subdirectory i can only choose this folder.

Comment: Try clicking each source file in the left pane and looking at the file's target membership in the file inspector. Make sure the box is checked next to the appropriate build target.

Comment: i'll try on some files, and will write result. But there are a lot of files and i want solution which doesn't require click on all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use cmake tool for build xcode project from source.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you added the folder as a Folder Reference in Xcode, rather than adding the actual source files to the target.

When adding the existing source files and folder, ensure to expand the "Options" area in the file browser and select the "Create Groups" option for added folders.

Also ensure "Add to targets" has the correct target selected.